# thread exiting with uncaught exception

Tags: android

I am implementing the system andEngine multiplayer for first, then be able to adjust all imports and libraries and runs without any error in `MOTODEV`, but the emulator "has stopped unexpectedly".

You can see [code here](http://code.google.com/r/nemoryoliver-andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/MultiplayerExample.java?r=0f271e101598cebc1f5c9b7692c5fe469eea1073).

Error on emulator:

```
08-02 00:52:55.500: D/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
08-02 00:52:55.500: W/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.multiplayerand/com.multiplayerand.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.multiplayerand.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.multiplayerand-2.apk]
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.multiplayerand.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.multiplayerand-2.apk]
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-02 00:52:55.549: E/AndroidRuntime(330):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this line from your log:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.multiplayerand/com.multiplayerand.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.multiplayerand.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

That line says,you tried to `instantiate activity` that it's name is `MainActivity` and it would be in `com.multiplayerand` pakage,but system could not find any Activity with this Component-info,and so java.lang.`ClassNotFoundException` has been occurred.

I guess you can solve problem if you:

- Check that your Activity name be `MainActivity`.
- Check that `MainActivity` be in package with name `com.multiplayerand`.
- Check that you registered MainActivity in `manifest` of your project.

Comment: <pre> ` <activity android:name="MainActivity" `<code>
                   change to MultiplayerExample
                   

Cool, after reading this, fixed in 2 seconds, thanks so much.

Comment: @Lucas Rodrigues Sena If it is true please add checkmark to my answer.

Comment: Could you please explain how to register the MainActivity in manifest?